# Neovim looks strange in a GNU screen socket.(OS X)

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, xterm, neovim

I installed GNU Screen using Homebrew. My $SHELL is zsh and also I'm using neovim.
Although my vim colorscheme works fine in local environment, it doesn't work properly in GNU Screen.
In my ~/.zshrc, I set like this: `export TERM=xterm-256color`.
In ~/.screenrc,

```
term screen-256color
termcap xterm*  xn:hs@
attrcolor b ".I"
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
termcapinfo xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@
defbce on
altscreen on
```

But when I open a screen session and run `vim`(I aliased `vim` to `nvim`), It looks like that `xterm-256color` doesn't works.
[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loYkI.png) .
Because I installed GNU Screen with Homebrew, color-256 is capable according to the greeting page which I can see after running `screen`. So re-compiling the source wouldn't be helpful I think.

It would be really grateful if somebody handles this irritating problem. Thank you.

Comment: Vim uses `termguicolors` to try to use gui highlights in the term for truecolor terminals. Do you have something similar enabled in neovim?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Actually `termguicolors` is enabled in `init.vim`. BTW, I moved to tmux instead of using GNU screen because of this problem. Thanks anyway for your comment!

Comment: Np! I’ve found tmux to work way better too :P